# Hollow cylinder pressure tolerance

Tags: pressure, material-science

I have a physics\material science problem.

We have a hollow cylinder with length L, inner diameter d and outer D made of a material with known mechanical properties(whatever constants are needed). The L >> d or D, meaning that we consider only radial expansion. How much of internal pressure can it hold before it breaks? Any ideas about how to tackle the problem?

Comment: Please specify the mechanical properties.

Comment: Also specify which side of the cylinder experiences the higher pressure (e.g., inside or outside).

Comment: the interior is pressurized.

Comment: Exact numbers for material properties doesn't matter. The problem can be solved for a generalized case.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an engineering problem. There are some simple estimates for cylindrical shells:

[Thin wall cylinder](https://www.engineersedge.com/pressure,045vessel/thin_wall_pressure_vessels_13909.htm)
[Thick wall cylinder](https://www.engineersedge.com/pressure,045vessel/thick_cylindrical_shells_13910.htm)

The maximum pressure depends on the material, type of weld, radius, wall thickness, and corrosion allowance. For a thin cylinder with circumferential stress (because the welds are longitudinal) the equation is:

$t = \frac{PR}{SE-0.6P}$

where $t$ is the thickness, $P$ is the pressure, $R$ is the inner radius, $S$ is the maximum stress (something like 15,000 psi for steel), and $E$ is a factor near 1 based on the weld seams. If $P$ is small compared to $S$ then the thickness scales linearly with pressure and with radius. But if $P$ approaches the "yield" (tensile strength) of the material then it will fail regardless of the thickness (eventually the atoms in a crystal are displaced too far by the pressure and the stress-strain relationship fails).